# Open a new dedicated terminal while running a command in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I want to open a new terminal when i enter a user-defined command in linux. Means for an example,when i type a command `tcpdump` in terminal and this will open a new session terminal for the tcpdump.

So in newly opened terminal, for capturing the packet, i have to write only `-i eth0` and not `tcpdump -i eth0`. The new terminal will internally take the command `tcpdump`.

So will these be possible?

Comment: How do you connect to a Linux session right now?  For example, do you use a GUI with xterm, or do you connect using an emulator on Windows?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume that you want to run the command in a new terminal window on your (Linux) desktop. Most terminal emulators seem to have an option `-e` for running commands, so you could do something like this:

```
urxvt -e $SHELL -c 'read -p "Options: " OPTS; tcpdump $OPTS' &
```

Replace `urxvt` with `aterm`, `xterm`, `Konsole` or whatever terminal emulator you're using.

If you want the window to remain open after the command finishes, you have to take additional steps (`urxvt` has an option `-hold` for this, but other terminal emulators don't).

Answer (score 0):

You could get a nice interpreter interface using [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap) (which you can probably install through your distribution's package manager).

```
while rlwrap -o -P "tcpdump " -C tcpdump sh; do :; done
```

This will give you a shell where the command-line line already has "tcpdump " at the beginning. It will also keep a history of the commands you previously ran using the command.

Run `exit 1` to quit the shell.

You could use Ansgar Wiechers' method to run the command in a new terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

You could try terminator, then splitting windows per command or modify some script I wrote to ssh per server, to split per command would need some work for that to happen but all possible https://github.com/vahidhedayati/termssh